# call object method instead of global method in js new Function

Tags: function, object, eval

i try make editor that allow user attach function to dynamic objects
each object have init method, allow user attach some actions on user input

think about this
user select baby and write in textarea

```
  move(1)
```

then select tank and insert in text area

```
onEnter(){
  fire(1)
}
```

we have baby and tank and some other dynamic objects
i pass code from text area to each object initActions function

```
Baby{
  move(number){
    //some action here...
  }
  initActions(code){
    this.init = Function(code)
    this.init()
}
```

that cause this error

```
ReferenceError: move is not defined
```

in baby object initActions
how can i make move available from parent object in function call

Answer (score 0):

someone answered me on irc channel

```
evalWith(target, code) {
            const keys = [], values = [];
            for (let o = target; o; o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o))
                for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
                    //console.log(o, key)
                    try{
                    let value = target[key];
                    if (typeof value === "function")
                        value = value.bind(target);
                    keys.push(key);
                    values.push(value);
                    }catch(e){
                        //console.log(o,key)
                    }
                }
    
            return Function(keys, code).apply(null, values);
        }
```